# How to Write Excel Formula to Check for Event A occuring within 24 hours of Event B

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the following:

I have table 1, which has the following columns:

1. a list of names,
2. time that each individual experienced event A.

| Name | EventA_Time |
| --- | --- |
| John | 13/4/2021 13:00 |
| Mark | 13/4/2021 16:00 |
| John | 16/5/2021 14:00 |

In table 2, I have

1. list of names (some of which are in table 2)
2. time that each individual experienced event B.

| Name | EventB_Time |
| --- | --- |
| John | 13/4/2021 17:00 |
| David | 13/4/2021 16:00 |
| John | 17/5/2021 12:00 |

I would like to identify who experienced event B within 24 hours of event A (i.e. appear in Both tables AND Event B occurs within 24 hours of event A)

What I've done:

1. in table 1, create a column which is EventA_time+24 hours, this creates the range for reference

| Name | EventA_Time | EventA_time + 24hr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 13/4/2021 13:00 | 14/4/2021 13:00 |
| Mark | 13/4/2021 16:00 | 14/4/2021 16:00 |
| John | 16/5/2021 14:00 | 17/5/2021 14:00 |

2. Identify those who appear in table2 using a VLOOKUP based on NAME, and pull the EventB_time across to table 1

| Name | EventA_Time | EventA_time + 24hr | EventB_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 13/4/2021 13:00 | 14/4/2021 13:00 | 13/4/2021 17:00 |
| Mark | 13/4/2021 16:00 | 14/4/2021 16:00 | N/A |
| John | 16/5/2021 14:00 | 17/5/2021 14:00 | 13/4/2021 17:00 |

I can then check if EventB_Time occurs within the EventA_Time and EventA_time + 24 hours range.

However the obvious problem is that this only works for the first occurance of the name in Table 2. If the Person experiences event B twice, it doesn't work - as it didn't for John's 2nd entry in table 2

Any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365, try the following formula on H10:

```
=FILTER($B$10:$B$12,INT(($F10=$B$2:$B$4) * ($G10>=$B$10:$B$12) * ($A$10:$A$12=$E10)),"")
```

Drag it down to fill the other cells. Adapt the formula to your tables. The formula also assumes that there are no multiples EventBs for the same name during the next 24 hours following EventA.

[image: Results]